# not getting the results from a bootloader

Tags: assembly, nasm, boot, qemu

I just wrote this piece of code in assembly but when i compile it with nasm and execute the image with QEMU all i get is Booting from floppy...
these are the instuctions i use

```
 nasm -f bin ENSIASiX.asm -o ENSIASiX.bin
 dd if=/dev/null of=ENSIASiX.img count=1 bs=512
 dd if=ENSIASiX.bin of=ENSIASiX.img conv=notrunc
 qemu -fda ENSIASiX.img -boot a
```

this is the assembly code i wrote i don't know if the problem is with the code or the way i assembl it

```
bits 16         ; system 16-BITS 

org 0x7C00      ; BIOS Boot Original
jmp Main

memoryerror:

MOV SI, errorr

CALL PrintString

RET



 PrintCharacter:    ; a function to print characters in the screen 



MOV AH, 0x0E        ;telling the BIOS that we want to print one character on screen

MOV BH, 0x00        ;the number of the page where to print the character 

MOV BL, 0x07        ;the color is light-grey font on black background 

INT 0x10            ;call video interruption

RET                 ;returning from calling procedure







PrintString:        ;the procedure to print string on screen

NextCharacter:      ;label to fetch the next character from string

    MOV AL,[SI]         ;take a byte from the string and store it in AL register

    INC SI              ;increment SI to get the next_character

    OR AL, AL           ;Check if it's the end of the string 

    JZ ExitFunction     ;Jump to ExitFunction label if the result is zero (END OF STRING)

    CALL PrintCharacter ;Else call the function PrintCharacter 

    JMP NextCharacter   ;take the next character 

ExitFunction:       ;the end of function label

    RET                 ;returning from calling procedure



Main:
MOV SI, Welcome     ;Store String in pointer to SI " Welcome User to the RATM V 0.5 BootLoader for ENSIASiX operating System "

CALL PrintString    ; call the function to print the string stored in SI

MOV SI, Wait_MSG    ;store string in pointer to SI 

CALL PrintString    ;call the function to print the string stored in SI

MOV AH, 0        

INT 0x16            ;AH = 0 and Interruption 0x16 for get keystroke from keyboard

XOR AX, AX          ;make AX register null

INT 0x12            ;Interruption for Detecting low Memory

JC  memoryerror     ; Carry is set if not enough memory

TEST AX, AX         ;Test the AX register with itself 

JZ  memoryerror     ; Zero is set if not enough memory

MOV SI, memory_enough ; string 'size is enough in RAM :D' message to SI

CALL PrintString    ; printing the message 'size is enough in RAM :D'

JMP $               ;infinite loop 


Welcome db 'Welcome User to the RATM V 0.5 BootLoader for ENSIASiX operating System',0 ;the welcome string ending with 0 

Wait_MSG db 'Press any key to continue ...',0                                          ;wait message string ending with 0

errorr db 'Memory Error ... ',0                                                           ;not enough memory error ending with 0

memory_enough db 'size is enough in RAM :D'

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0   ;Fill the rest of sector with 0

DW 0xAA55                   ;Add boot signature at the end of boot-loader
```

Comment: Should not the very first line be "bits 16"? Bootloader code is always 16 bits, then it could switch to 32 or 64 bits code.

Comment: i changed it to bits 16 still the same thing no messages are shown

Comment: Works fine here. Nevertheless you should initialize `CS` and `DS` because the BIOS might not have set it as you expect. Also, this is advanced programming, you are expected to be able to use a debugger.

Comment: Thnx a lot problem fixed

Comment: Your source code is commented well.  I just clicked your question +1 for that one reason alone.  Make sure that, in any future questions, you also comment your source code clearly like you have done here.  Good job @RidaAmine !